# SSRS Report: Using Tables from a SQL and Azure database in a report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I have an existing SSRS report that is using tables from our SQL server db. We have recently moved one of the tables in the report to our Azure db which sits on a different server. I have read that I can create a linked server in SMSS to join the tables, but unsure how this would help me amending my report.

Is it possible for me to connected the SQL and Azure db tables in my SSRS report? Also, even if I can, would it be a good idea? I have read about Elastic database queries, but not sure if that is just within the Azure server or can it connect between Azure and SQL server?

Thanks for any tips, links or advice. Brent

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by creating a linked server as mentioned in the [article](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0016.htm) step by step. Then create a new data source in your report pointing to master database. While defining the Dataset you can use a query like below joining the tables from Azure SQL Database and On-Premise SQL Database:

```
select * from [AdventureWorksLTOnAzure].[databasename].[SalesLT].[Customer] a
inner join AdventureWorks2019.Sales.Customer b on a.customerid = b.CustomerID
```

You can customize the query as you would want.

However, there are performance costs that come with linked servers. When the data grows or more number of tables joined or adding multiple filters and more, all these could impact your query performance and hence the report too.

It would be better if all tables for the report exist in same database server.